# jQuery extension to select an HTML/Dom node

Tags: jquery-plugins

I'm looking for a jQuery plugin/extension that allows me to select a specific DOM element/node, much like the Chrome web inspector of Firebug do.

For example::

[image]

I'm not in need of any functionality other than highlighting the node and being able to access the DOM node.

Any thoughts or directions would be appreciated.

Comment: I just found this: http://rockingcode.com/tutorial/element-dom-tree-jquery-plugin-firebug-like-functionality/ If anyone has any other ones they can think of, I'd love to see those as well.

Comment: why this question tagged on jQuery?

Comment: because I'm looking for a jQuery extension.